# How can I remove java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, exception, numberformatexception

why does my code throws exception without taking a single input??

```
import java.util.*;
public class program3{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in the array");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int[] arr = new int[n];

    try{
        System.out.println("Enter the elements in the array");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String j = sc.nextLine();
            int k = Integer.parseInt(j);
            arr[i]=k;
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the index of the array element you want to access");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The array element at index "+a+" = "+arr[a]);
        System.out.println("The array element successfully accessed");
    }
    catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

I need to generate NumberFormatException when I provide an input other than int. Instead, it is generated without taking any input.

This is the error message

```
Enter the number of elements in the array
2
Enter the elements in the array
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Comment: Did you use sc.nextInt() earlier in your code (maybe to accept the value of n)?  The reason I ask is that a call to `sc.nextLine()` immediately after a call to one of `Scanner`'s `nextXXX()` methods (such as `nextInt()`, `nextDouble()`, `next()`, etc) might not work as you expect.  Instead of waiting for you to type a line, it might instead immediately return a string of zero or more blanks without waiting for you to type. Is that what is happening to you?

Comment: `String j = sc.nextLine(); if (j.matches("\\d+")) { int k = Integer.parseInt(j); arr[i]=k; } else { System.out.println("Nope! Try Again...."); }`

Answer (score -1):

First, it would be nice to see full code and an exception stacktrace to understand what exactly line of code does throw it. Currently `try` block is not closed, so this code example is just not valid.

It might be `int k = Integer.parseInt(j);`
It might be another line where you're reading `n` from input.

Second, could you try debugging and execute the code line-by-line to see exactly what is the `String` value and how it appeared?

Comment: Good suggestion on seeing full code and stacktrace, but you're not answering the question, so this should have been written as a comment. As for last paragraph, the error message already shows exactly what `String` value is (an empty string), so no need for debugging to figure that out.

Comment: The idea was to figure out how this empty string appeared - was it read from input sting or was it a default value, for example. And why this is not an answer to the question?

Comment: The empty string appeared in the previous line with the call to `nextLine()`, that seems pretty obvious. --- 1st paragraph: "we need full code and stacktrace". That's a good comment, not an answer. --- 2nd paragraph: "it might be `parseInt` or some other line". Not very helpful and it's a comment, not an answer. --- 3rd paragraph: "try debugging". That's a good comment, not an answer. --- In short, this "answer" is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea, than's for your clarification. The only thing - empty string reason is not so obvious since `n` is not defined. So there may be a `NumberFormatException` while reading `n` and `int k = Integer.parseInt(j);` is not executed at all. That seems more real for me.

Comment: Maybe, but I guess you haven't seen how often we get questions about `nextLine()` returning empty string because it was preceded by a `nextInt()` (or similar) call, so the probability that OP showed *this* code because this is where the error occurred and was caused by `nextInt()` before the loop, is a lot higher than probability of OP showing the wrong code (which admittedly has happened too, but probability is extremely low here).

Answer (score -1):

May be this is what you are trying to do., By doing it this way, you will be able to figure out, which input caused the problem for you.

```
   try
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println( "Enter the size of the array : " );
        String userInputValue = sc.nextLine().strip();
        System.out.println( "Your input for arraySize is : " + userInputValue );

        if( userInputValue.isBlank() )
        {
            throw new NumberFormatException( "Empty value cannot be added as array size" );
        }

        int n = Integer.parseInt( userInputValue.strip() );  // size of the array, this also will be the size of the input from user
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        System.out.println( "Enter the elements in the array" );
        for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            String j = sc.nextLine();
            if( j.isBlank() )
            {
                throw new NumberFormatException( "Empty value cannot be added as array element " );
            }
            int k = Integer.parseInt( j.strip() ); // Strip added to remove possible leading and trailing whitespaces from user input
            arr[i] = k;
        }

        System.out.println( "Elements you entered are : " );
        for( int i : arr )
        {
            System.out.print( i + " " );
        }
    }
    catch( NumberFormatException e )
    {
        System.out.println( "Input value is not valid : " + e.getMessage() );
    }
```

Comment: You sure don't want to create `Scanner` inside the loop, and the question code very likely asks the user for `n`, which is extremely likely the cause of the problem. Besides, the error in the question clearly shows an attempt at parsing an empty string as a number, so calling `strip()` is certainly not going to fix that.

Comment: @Andreas I've updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out that `Scanner` inside the loop

Comment: So what exactly did you do to fix the problem? There is no description. --- I know, you replaced the `nextInt()` we can't see in the question with a `nextLine()`, right? Well, that just makes this answer a duplicate of the answers in the linked question up top.